# Python -- change the RGB values of the image and save as a image

Tags: python, image, rgb, python-imaging-library

I can read every pixel' RGB of the image already, but I don't know how to change the values of RGB to a half and save as a image.Thank you in advance.

```
from PIL  import *

def half_pixel(jpg):
  im=Image.open(jpg)
  img=im.load()
  print(im.size)
  [xs,ys]=im.size  #width*height

# Examine every pixel in im
  for x in range(0,xs):
     for y in range(0,ys):
        #get the RGB color of the pixel
        [r,g,b]=img[x,y]
```

Comment: This one here looks like what you're trying to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825217/edit-rgb-values-in-a-jpg-with-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do everything you are wanting to do within PIL.

If you are wanting to reduce the value of every pixel by half, you can do something like:

```
import PIL

im = PIL.Image.open('input_filename.jpg')
im.point(lambda x: x * .5)
im.save('output_filename.jpg')
```

You can see more info about point operations here: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/handbook/tutorial.html#point-operations

Additionally, you can do arbitrary pixel manipulation as:
`im[row, col] = (r, g, b)`

Answer (score 3):

- get the RGB color of the pixel

  ```
  [r,g,b]=img.getpixel((x, y))
  ```
- update new rgb value

  ```
   r = r + rtint
   g = g + gtint
   b = b + btint
   value = (r,g,b)
  ```
- assign new rgb value back to pixel

  ```
  img.putpixel((x, y), value)
  ```

Comment: Why did people downvote this?  This is the answer that covers the case with different coefficients for each color channel.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this with Pillow. You can use [Image.point](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.point), for example.

```
# Function to map over each channel (r, g, b) on each pixel in the image
def change_to_a_half(val):
    return val // 2

im = Image.open('./imagefile.jpg')
im.point(change_to_a_half)
```

The function is actually only called 256 times (assuming 8-bits color depth), and the resulting map is then applied to the pixels. This is much faster than running a nested loop in python.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Numpy and Matplotlib installed, one solution would be to convert your image to a numpy array and then e.g. save the image with matplotlib.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open(jpg)
arr = np.array(img)
arr = arr/2 # divide each pixel in each channel by two 
plt.imsave('output.png', arr.astype(np.uint8))
```

Be aware that you need to have a version of PIL >= 1.1.6

Comment: You also need to have numpy and matlibplot installed. So if they are not already using those libraries, this is not the easiest solution.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right will edit this information to the post. It's personal preference in the end I guess. I like to stay as much within numpy as possible and find the PIL library really clumsy.